# Link to download Oracle SQL*plus 8.0

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I wanted to download the Oracle SQL*plus 8.0 as we are learning SQL in college, but I was unable to. Please can anyone send me the link to the download.

Comment: That's waaaaaaaaaaaay too old. You can ask Oracle for install media if you have an Oracle support contract, but those are not publicly available any more AFAIK.

Comment: please ask oracle how to download their product.

Answer (score 3):

We had 8.0.5 and 8.0.6 versions of Oracle Database/SQL*Plus that were popular 20 years ago or so.

I really hope your class isn't using that platform to teach you SQL.

You can request older media if you have an account with My Oracle Support, but you won't have one of those, and I'm not sure they can pull versions that old even if you did.

Find what version of the database you are connected to for your class. That's what is more important. You can then download an instant client that is compatible with that version of the database [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)

SQL Developer is also free and a good place to learn and practice your SQL. It's a GUI vs a CLI - both have their pros & cons, but you should probably be used to both if you're going to pursue a career in IT.